# New Instagram design for embeds broke whole site (flexbox, css)

Tags: css, flexbox, instagram, embed

I'm facing a new issue with Instagram embeds, on the previous version of embeds, it created an iframe and all was ok. But the new embeds "recreates" blocks of code and insert stylesheets to parent site, which means, all CSS styles that were used, breaking the whole site design.

The main issue is in this file:
https://www.instagram.com/static/bundles/base/EmbedSDK.css/e46f41123c91.css

And when you look at the definitions:

```
#react-root, article, div, footer, header, main, nav, section {
-webkit-box-align: stretch;
-webkit-align-items: stretch;
-ms-flex-align: stretch;
align-items: stretch;
border: 0 solid #000;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
-webkit-box-direction: normal;
-webkit-flex-direction: column;
-ms-flex-direction: column;
flex-direction: column;
-webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
-ms-flex-negative: 0;
flex-shrink: 0;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: relative; }
```

Then you probably see where is main issue... when this code is inserted to any page, 100% must be breaking the whole site, because the layout is based on new flexbox technology. The main question is why Instagram remove the iframe, where can use anything and place this to site, where is called

```
<script async defer src="//www.instagram.com/embed.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think the issue you have to solve is "how to fix this", maybe a workaround... because "why IG removes the iframe" can only be answered by IG itself. Their new navigation is making some things very difficult to interact with...

Comment: thanks guys, but im really not sure, if IG has a bug reporting